# Backbone Fetch Not Returning a Result

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js

Simple answer to this I'm sure but can't seem to get it working.

```
var DailyModel = BaseModel.extend({

    initialize: function() {},

    parse: function(res){
        console.log(res);
    },

    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama'

});

return DailyModel;
```

In chrome, under network I'm getting the same referral and requested url as the virtual host for the application ( ie. web.myapp.local ). In the end, the parse function is not running.

Comment: Step into the fetch call and see where it's stopping.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you might want to make sure that your initialize method does what you want it to do

change

```
initialize: function() {}
```

to

```
initialize: function() {
   BaseModel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This is because Backbone does not provide inheritance everywhere.

Secondly, I'm sure you're going to have a nice error like

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama. Origin web.myapp.local
>   is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

so instead you'll have to use JSONP and you can ready about that on the twitter API page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know. You basically append a querystring `callback=MyCallbackFunction`

Comment: Thanks for the help, these are some good changes and i've incorporated them but any request I'm making with .getJson or .ajax is still returning the html for web.myapp.local/index.php. If the url for any ajax request is not relative it returns this page.

Comment: Figured out the problem - I was using mockjax, a javascript library to intercept ajax calls and it was causing the problems. Solved it by completely removing the library. Thanks anyway.